# Getting last event per day from mysql database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

We have a CRM application to monitor employees check ins and check outs of every location (clients).

I'm requested to get the **last check out of a specific employee per day**.

My database looks like this:

| employee_id | check in time | check out time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 1666536812 | 1666537080 |
| 90 | 1653467778 | 1653474758 |
| 90 | 1653467444 | 1653474321 |

Every employee has **multiple check outs per day**, I need to get the last one per day.

My attempt so far:

```
$this->db->order_by('check_out_time desc');
$this->db->where('employee_id', $user_id);
$query = $this->db->get('events',50);
```

```
foreach($events as $event){
   // Change event(check out) time from epoch format to normal format
   $checkOutTime = new DateTime("@".$event->check_out_time);
   $event->check_out_time = $checkOutTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   // get day if this event
   $day =$checkOutTime->format('Y-m-d');

   // set the "visits[day] to max value of that day
   if (!isset($visits[$day]) || $visits[$day] < $event->check_out_time )
      $visits[$day] = $event->check_out_time;
}
```

Output:
[image]

The output is visually what i want but the data is incorrect.

Comment: try to use `$this->db->limit(1);` after `$this->db->order_by('check_out_time desc');` line, You will get last `check_out_time` single row

Comment: @M.Hemant just tried it, it changed nothing

Comment: just realized that the minutes and seconds is correct but the hours is behind with 3 hours, trying to figure out why.

Comment: i think you should add `$this->db->where(DATE(check_out_time),'$date');` condition with above condition and loop this query so you will get each day last `check_out_time`

Comment: @M.Hemant my code is working but the hours is incorrect, cant find out why

Comment: @Yazan Check what timezone your Codegniter and mysql is using. For example, you can check Codeigniter timezone in Config > App.php public $appTimezone = 'America/Chicago'; May be timezone causing you hours difference